# What does it mean in parentheses word (EVENT),in html,and why I have to write it down?without that (event) all the code will not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

html

```
<div id="cube" onmousemove= coordinate(event)></div>
<p id= "text"></p>
```

css

```
#cube{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

and js

```
function cordinate(a){
     var x = a.clientX;
     var y = a.clientY;
     var cor = "cordinates: " + x + "  " + y;
     document.getElementById("text").innerHTML= cor;
```

this is code for mouse-cordinate of div "cube"

Answer (score 1):

In an `onXXX` attribute, `event` is a variable that contains an object with information about the action that caused the handler to be triggered. For instance, in `onmousemove`, the event object contains the mouse coordinates in the `clientX` and `clientY` properties.

You can read detailed documentation about the `Event` object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

[This site](http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object) has some more details on how the `event` object is passed to event handlers, depending on how you define them.

Comment: where else can be found for example that the event in such a way used?

Comment: event will be undefined in old IEs so you need to check window.event too, e.g.:  event = event || window.event;

Comment: @Shautieh Unless there's a local `event` variable that shadows it, `event` will be treated as `window.event`.

Answer (score 0):

The "onmousemove" attribute allows you to attach javascript code to the <div> element that is execute when your mouse move around inside that partcular <div> element.

You can put in any piece of javascript code.  Without the parentheses, you are basically referencing a function, you're not actually invoking it.  With the parenthesis you are invoking it.

Comment: How does this answer the question of what the `event` argument means?

Comment: @Barmar was the question specifically about the event argument or the parenthesis (or more accurately brackets)?  If it is specifically about the event argument, then yes it does not answer it.

Comment: The question is in the title.

Comment: @Barmar Yes there's potentially 2 questions in the title, I answered one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The `event` object is generated by [DOM's event system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

A [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) will be passed to your [mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) (`cordinate()`) you installed as `a`.
This allows your handler to get details of the event.

You are using `a.clientX` and `a.clientY` in `cordinate()`. So your code won't work if you don't pass `event` to the handler.

Do read the above links and MDN in general to understand more on the topic.

Comment: It's not a shorthand to window.event, as window.event is not defined in old browsers... window.event is more IE oriented.